# C++ how to tell developer to implement sth. when designing a template (like Java interface)

Tags: c++, generic-programming

I'm new to C++, and I have this question because I try to compare C++ to Java.

In Java, `interface` tell the developer which function to implement in order to use the Class or function I provide. For example, by specify the param type as `Runnable`, I tell the developer that the param I accepted need to have a `run` method, `Iterable` tells that the object need to have an iterator.

In C++, so far as I learned, I have encounter many cases that in compiling time, the compiler ask for some operator. And sometimes I even don't know how to specify the requirement of the param that others pass in.

To summarize my question, what's the general idea of approach when designing an template that I hope can handle more generic usage?

I know C++ is not an 100% object-orient language, so I'm still trying to get used to it, when shifting from Java.

Comment: One should never implement sith.  They are the dark side.

Comment: It all depends on your needs and use-cases. For example, do you need to compare two objects for equality? Then create and implement an `operator==` function. If you don't need to compare for equality, then don't create that operator for your type.

Comment: You probably mean well, but such a question will be marked as too broad and be closed. Instead I'd recommend you don't learn C++ by comparing to Java, as the two languages are vastly different and instead get a good C++ book to study from.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for *concepts*, you can utilize [boost.concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) for example

Comment: " I try to compare C++ to Java." - two languages could hardly be more different, except for some trivial syntax for things like loops.

Comment: You should [read the manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for whatever template class/function you are using, it will explain what the parameter requirements are.

Comment: @ZiqiLiu "I know C++ is not an 100% object-orient language" lol
here you are: <>(((°>

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Java interfaces are for runtime polymorphism; in C++ they are plain classes that contain only pure virtual methods. Java needs a separate language entity for them as it supports only single inheritance for classes (which simplifies many corner cases) but allows multiple inheritance of interfaces; as C++ allows full multiple inheritance for classes in general, there's no need for this distinction.

OTOH, in C++ you don't use interfaces nearly as often - especially in the standard library, especially in the container part. Often compile-time polymorphism is used, in the form of templates.

Unfortunately as of today there's no way to express what operations should a type parameter of a template provide; the template-equivalent of interfaces - "concepts" - is being worked on by the C++ standard committee - unfortunately since many years now - and it's not ready yet.

For now you may only spell out your requirements in the documentation. If a type passed to the template doesn't satisfy them, you'll just get a compilation error pointing to the template code that tries to do something the type doesn't support. This leads to quite some confusion and horrible error messages, so you can try to mitigate this by strategically placing `static_assert` about the provided type checking if it conforms to what you need, thus providing better diagnostics in case of error.

Comment: You can implement a light form of required abilities of some template argument through expressions in auto -> decltype() function declarations, right?

Comment: @Shaggi: hmm I cannot understand what you mean, may you provide an example of such a declaration?

Comment: Have a look, I think it expresses the idea: https://godbolt.org/g/kfa1s8

Comment: Aah I see! Yes, you can use something like that, but I fear that generally either it's not enough (think how you would shoehorn all requirements for `std::sort` in such an expression), or the return value isn't related to the properties required from the type (think `std::sort` again).

Comment: You can do a comma-expression (put a void() at the end or similar), but yeah it probably won't cover all cases.